# Designing a Generic Toolmanager 

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, model-view-controller, design-patterns, flex4

I want to handle multiple operations on a UI Component (button ,textfield, swfs,custom objects etc)

in like scaling,skewing ,color,rotations etc etc and save them too. Earlier the actions were done

using  a single tool and single mxml file but now the tool is separated into different tools.

Was wondering how i can design / use something like Toolmanager class to handle actions etc?

Also the tricky part is that some objects can have more operations defined for them .
Like 'object1' has 3 operations that can be performed on it and 'object2' has 5 operations defined on it.

We are using MVC design pattern but no frameworks as such.

What are the different design patterns that can be used to do this?

**Edit:**
To be more precise i want implement this in AS3 OO way.
The application is similar to drawing application which supports addition of various images,text,audio,swfs etc. One added user can perform various operations of the objects..like
adding color,scaling skewing,rotation etc etc and custom effects and after that export the drawing as PNG.Likewise some effects that are applicable to text are not applicable to images 
and vice versa. and some effects can be common.

Any ideas?

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you're asking for.  Is it possible to be more specific in your question?

Comment: i've added an edit now..does it help?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you could have a toolbar, tools(inheriting from a common base), and some kind of property panel, these objects are accessible from a manager class which wrappes them together and makes some variables accessible for all classes.
Probably you want a selection array or vector in the manager class and a select tool to manipulate this collection

like (in the manager)

```
protected var _selection:Vector.<EditableBase> = new Vector.<EditableBase>();
public function get selection() { return _selection;}
```

and a collection about the editbase extensions and the tools avaiable for them.
every time the selection tool updates the selection collection (probably calling a method on manager from the select tool's onMouseUp method) you can update the toolbar to display the apropriate tools for the current selection

(in manager)

```
protected var _ToolsByType:Object (or Dictionary) = {"EditableAudio": ["toolA", "toolB", etc]};
protected var _defaultSet:Array = ["toolA", "toolB"];
```

and after the selection has benn manipulated (in manager also)

```
public function onSelectionChangedCallback():void
{
  var toolsToDisplay:Array = _defaultSet;
  if(_selection.length == 1)
  {
   //not actual syntax
   var type:String = getQualifiedClassName(_selection[0]);
   if(type in _ToolsByType) toolsToDisplay = _ToolsByType[type];
  }

  myToolBar.showSet(toolsToDisplay);
}
```

the ancestor for the tools should look something like this:

```
public class ToolBase
{
  protected var _manager:ToolManager;
  function ToolBase(manager:ToolManager)//and probably a bunch of other params as well
  {
     _manager = manager;
  }
  function onSelect()
  {
    //you can manipulate the properties panel here
  }
  function onDeSelect()...
  function onMouseDown(mouseData:event/whateverWrapperYouHaveCreated)...
  function onMouseMove...
  function onMouseUp...
}
```

and so and so on :)
kinda straight forward.
check photoshop plugin tutorials, or google around "extending {any adobe stuff here, like flash or something}
thats javascript but the concept can be applied here as well

Comment: nice thx for the answer.. i was wondering having one single toolmanger class and handling all user actions thr?  associating a command to every action and executing it..does it makes sense? also any links for the references u mentioned? wasnt able to find much.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use the Strategy Design Pattern by creating some extra classes in your MVC implementation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

algo, check this tool for images:
http://www.senocular.com/demo/TransformToolAS3/TransformTool.html

bye! :)